# getResources in non-activity class

Tags: android, resources, android-context

I've been trying to load a bitmap in a non-activity class but everything I've done so far has failed. I have even tried to send the Context as reference, but this also results in error.

My current situation looks like this:

```
// Surface class
public class GameScreen extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
    TileSet ts;

    public GameScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        // Here I send context as a reference
        ts = new TileSet(context, R.drawable.tiles);
    }
}


// This is the class I need to get resources
public class TileSet {
    public TileSet(Context context, int id) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just getting the bitmap in the Activity and then passing that to the constructor of your GameScreen?

Comment: I have thought of that, but I was hoping there would be another better solution.. well, I'll try it then, it will probably work... thanks

Comment: This isn't a necessarily inelegant way of doing things. Also, if you think my answer is good, please upvote and/or accept it.